# How come this Poisson formula equals 1

Tags: probability, statistics

In Poisson Random Variable:
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}=1$$
Why does this equal $1$? What property is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$
e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {x^n \over n!}
$$
for $x\in\mathbb R$. Hence,
$$
\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda}=1
$$
and this shows that
$$
f(x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}
$$
is the probability mass function of a random variable $X$ taking values in $\{1,2,\ldots\}$.